# On Click Select drop down font color issue and default value issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

When I select value show white while I am on the same div, But when I go to another div and click that, the selected value is the same and color still white and not black.

When we do not select and the default value should be appear i.e other curr..

```js
$(".menu > div").click(function() {
  $(".menu > div.selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected")
})
$(".menu1 > div").click(function() {
  $(".menu1 > div.selected1").removeClass("selected1");
  $(this).addClass("selected1")
})
```

```css
.botborder2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 1) !important;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

.currn-box {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240) !important;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.currn-box:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.currn-select5 {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240) !important;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px !important;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #f0f0f0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 90px;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
}

.currn-select5:hover,
.select-color:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-color {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.select-color:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.selected {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px 4px;
}

select .selected1,
.select-color {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff !important;
}

.nobackground {
  background-color: none !important;
  background: none !important;
}

.noround2 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row menu" style="padding: 15px;margin: 0px auto;">
  <div class="col-2 currn-box">
    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><br> USD
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 currn-box">
    <i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><br> POUND
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 currn-select5 menu1">
    <select class="select-color form-control nobackground noround2 botborder2">
      <option class="currn-select" value="" style="color: #000 !importants;">OTHER CURR..</option>
      <option value="&#x0024; Canadian Dollar" class="currn-select" value="" style="color: #000 !importants;">&#x0024; Canadian Dollar </option>
      <option value="&#36; Hong Kong Dollar" class="currn-select" value="" style="color: #000 !importants;">&#36; Hong Kong Dollar </option>
      <option value="&#165; Japanese Yen" class="currn-select" value="" style="color: #000 !importants;">&#165; Japanese Yen</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a (incomplete) support request that's just been copied and pasted in to stackoverflow?

Comment: Dear sir i have been trying to solve this since long but i did not get any luck so i put two question with the different line. because earlier also i asked but it was not appropriate way so i edit that and re-posted and same i raise another question with the same line due to quick solution. sorry if it get any problem.

Comment: Please rewrite the description into something other ppl can understand. I made you a working snippet with the framework you tagged. It seems to work as expected - except it is blue, not black and grey, not white

Comment: The issue is still appearing on the screen. The requirement is only when the click is off from the drop down div it get background grey and font is white, as the font is will come to black and div show grey in the deselected time, only on the time when click on div select at that time div will be in blue and font is white.  Also while doing toggled div  the drop down appear with the default value will appear.

Comment: inside your option tag you have typo `importants` should be `important` .

Comment: Thanks! but this is not the make any difference on the error solving

Comment: @user3181077 Hi, can you elaborate more on your issue . I didn't understood your problem

Comment: have you run the code, and try to click the the div if yes then you can see the drop down font color is white after we click on the other div. more the drop down font color need black or at least it look like visible.

Comment: Hi are you seeing that behaviour [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L2hs5znj/) ?

Comment: Dear Swait, the issue on the third box if you click on that and drop down font color is black instead of the white. after once you select any option and the font color goes to white this function is working correctly. but one you moved to click 2nd dive the font color keeps white it would not get auto change black. This is the major issue.